# Wedge product of two exact forms.

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-forms, several-complex-variables

Let $f,g \colon U \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be two holomorphic functions on a small open set $0 \in U\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ (or even germs at the origin) such that $f(0) = g(0) =0$. Suppose that the singular sets of the $1$-forms $\mbox{d}f$ and $\mbox{d}g$ have codimension at least two. If $$\mbox{d}f \wedge \mbox{d}g = 0,$$ is it possible to write $g$ in terms of $f$? This gives relations between the derivatives of $f$ and those of $g$. However, I was not able to figure out how to relate $g$ and $f$.

From the de Rham-Saito division lemma one can write $$\mbox{d}g = h \mbox{d}f,$$ for some nonvanishing holomorphic function $h$. Could someone provide an example where $h$ is not constant?

Comment: Two algebraically dependent polynomial functions?

Comment: For sure... taking $g$ to be a polynomial in $f$ provides a bunch of examples.

Comment: I think the most general setting for the wedge product to vanish is that the functions are, I should say, holomorphically dependent.

Comment: Maybe there are some restrictions due to the codimension of the singular set... It would be nice to write $g=p(f)$ for $p$ holomorphic, $p'(0) \neq 0$.

Comment: I am not an expert in this field, so that is pretty much all my inputs, but if you could find the sufficient and necessary condition, then I would be very happy to know.  If you find out, please post it here.

Comment: I think that if the singular set is empty it can be solved. the map $(f,g)\colon U \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ has constant rank equal to one. Then the image of some smaller open set $U' \subset U$ is an one dimensional submanifold $V$. Then a local equation for $V\subset\mathbb{C}^2$ gives an analytic relation to $f$ and $g$. Since $V$ s smooth one applies the implicit function theorem and find $g = p(f)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question to provide reference for those who encounter the same problem.

I've found a more general result in [Mattei, Moussu - Holonomie et intégrales premières](http://www.numdam.org/item/ASENS_1980_4_13_4_469_0/). And it reads as follows:

> Factorization Theorem:
>
> Let $f,g$ be germs of holomorphic functions at the origin of $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that $df\wedge dg =0$. If $f$ i not the power of another holomorphic funcion, then there exists a germ of $l$ of holomorphic function on at the origin of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $g = l \circ f$.